# How to understand the differences between Clonezilla Live and the "alternative" Clonezilla Live?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, backup, clone, clonezilla

How does one know whether they need the Debian-based Clonezilla Live, or the Ubuntu-based "alternative" Clonezilla Live?

[This FAQ](http://drbl.org/faq/fine-print.php?path=./2_System/57_why_ubuntu_based_clonezilla_live.faq#57_why_ubuntu_based_clonezilla_live.faq) provides a high-level outline of the differences, but unless the system has an i386 processor or uEFI, it is unclear why users would need the Ubuntu-based "alternative" version.

Interestingly, the [Clonezilla downloads page](http://clonezilla.org/downloads.php) currently lists the "alternative" version first.

Answer (score 6):

The Debian version only contains open software.  This means there is less support for hardware.

The Ubuntu version has more support, because it i t includes non-free firmware, and also supports uEFI secure boot.

Basically, You would have to look at Debian and Ubuntu's supported hardware to see if they include support for your hardware.